# How to scale svg image with css

Tags: css, svg

How can I set the css to scale a graphic used as the background of this SVG button in a video player:

```
<button class="fullscreen btn"></button>
```

CSS

```
.fullscreen 
{
background: url(fullscreen.svg) 50% 50% no-repeat;
right: 15px;
background-size: 17px 14px;
width: 24px;
}
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mattography/wujs6gpy/)

Comment: Does the SVG have a viewBox, if not give it one.

Comment: The button is created dynamically with this JS:
`videoObj.fullScreenBtn = document.createElement("button");
          videoObj.fullScreenBtn.className = "fullscreen btn";`, so how would I add the `viewBox` property?

Comment: I've updated the question with a fiddle. The image won't show up, but it does in my project. I'm trying to figure out how to get it to scale to a larger size when the browser is enlarged and shrink down when the player is brought to a smaller size.

Comment: You add the viewBox to fullscreen.svg

Comment: I've tried adding it dynamically with `videoObj.fullScreenBtn.className = "fullscreen btn" + "viewBox='20 20 20 20'";`, but this just knocks out the image.